# How to get the HTTP direct link of an SVN file by filling in the account password in the query

Tags: apache, authentication, svn, url-rewriting

1. Now suppose:

Url1 means http://sas2.witersen.com:9094/svn/rep1/2023-03-11_165815.jpg is a normal SVN warehouse HTTP access address that requires permissions. The corresponding user permissions are: user user1 password 123456

Url2 means http://sas2.witersen.com:9094/svn_0328/rep1/2023-03-11_165815.jpg?u=user1&p=123456 is another URL

Now I want to achieve the following effects:

- Users need to enter their account password to access url1
- Users can access the content of url2 without entering an account password, but url2 actively carries u and p information

2. this is my apache config file：

```
RewriteEngine On
##ProxyRequests Off
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^u=(.*?)&p=(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/svn_0328
RewriteRule ^/svn_0328(.*) /svn$1 [QSA,E=REMOTE_USER:%1,E=AUTH_PW:%2,L,P]

<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNListParentPath on
  SVNParentPath /home/svnadmin/rep/
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "SVN Repo"
  AuthUserFile /home/svnadmin/httpPasswd
  AuthzSVNAccessFile /home/svnadmin/authz
  Require valid-user
</Location>

<Location /svn_0328>
ProxyPass http://localhost/svn
ProxyPassReverse http://localhost/svn
Header set Destination "http://localhost%{REQUEST_URI}e" env=REQUEST_URI
</Location>
```

3. this is rewrite log

```
[Wed Apr 26 13:59:38.431691 2023] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 31648] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 61.54.163.93:47432] 61.54.163.93 - - [sas2.witersen.com/sid#5635f94d5ce0][rid#5635f94fab10/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /svn_0328/rep1/2023-03-11_165815.jpg
[Wed Apr 26 13:59:38.431719 2023] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 31648] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 61.54.163.93:47432] 61.54.163.93 - - [sas2.witersen.com/sid#5635f94d5ce0][rid#5635f94fab10/initial] applying pattern '^/svn_0328(.*)' to uri '/svn_0328/rep1/2023-03-11_165815.jpg'
[Wed Apr 26 13:59:38.431757 2023] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 31648] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 61.54.163.93:47432] 61.54.163.93 - - [sas2.witersen.com/sid#5635f94d5ce0][rid#5635f94fab10/initial] RewriteCond: input='u=user1&p=123456' pattern='^u=(.*?)&p=(.*)$' => matched
[Wed Apr 26 13:59:38.431761 2023] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 31648] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 61.54.163.93:47432] 61.54.163.93 - - [sas2.witersen.com/sid#5635f94d5ce0][rid#5635f94fab10/initial] RewriteCond: input='/svn_0328/rep1/2023-03-11_165815.jpg' pattern='^/svn_0328' => matched[Wed Apr 26 13:59:38.431764 2023] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 31648] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 61.54.163.93:47432] 61.54.163.93 - - [sas2.witersen.com/sid#5635f94d5ce0][rid#5635f94fab10/initial] rewrite '/svn_0328/rep1/2023-03-11_165815.jpg' -> '/svn/rep1/2023-03-11_165815.jpg'
[Wed Apr 26 13:59:38.431767 2023] [rewrite:trace5] [pid 31648] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 61.54.163.93:47432] 61.54.163.93 - - [sas2.witersen.com/sid#5635f94d5ce0][rid#5635f94fab10/initial] setting env variable 'REMOTE_USER' to ''
[Wed Apr 26 13:59:38.431769 2023] [rewrite:trace5] [pid 31648] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 61.54.163.93:47432] 61.54.163.93 - - [sas2.witersen.com/sid#5635f94d5ce0][rid#5635f94fab10/initial] setting env variable 'AUTH_PW' to ''
[Wed Apr 26 13:59:38.431773 2023] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 31648] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 61.54.163.93:47432] 61.54.163.93 - - [sas2.witersen.com/sid#5635f94d5ce0][rid#5635f94fab10/initial] forcing proxy-throughput with http://sas2.witersen.com:9094/svn/rep1/2023-03-11_165815.jpg
[Wed Apr 26 13:59:38.431776 2023] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 31648] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 61.54.163.93:47432] 61.54.163.93 - - [sas2.witersen.com/sid#5635f94d5ce0][rid#5635f94fab10/initial] go-ahead with proxy request proxy:http://sas2.witersen.com:9094/svn/rep1/2023-03-11_165815.jpg [OK]
[Wed Apr 26 13:59:38.441480 2023] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 31536] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 119.91.232.213:60792] 119.91.232.213 - - [sas2.witersen.com/sid#5635f94d5ce0][rid#5635f9507b60/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /svn/rep1/2023-03-11_165815.jpg
[Wed Apr 26 13:59:38.441500 2023] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 31536] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 119.91.232.213:60792] 119.91.232.213 - - [sas2.witersen.com/sid#5635f94d5ce0][rid#5635f9507b60/initial] applying pattern '^/svn_0328(.*)' to uri '/svn/rep1/2023-03-11_165815.jpg'
[Wed Apr 26 13:59:38.441503 2023] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 31536] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 119.91.232.213:60792] 119.91.232.213 - - [sas2.witersen.com/sid#5635f94d5ce0][rid#5635f9507b60/initial] pass through /svn/rep1/2023-03-11_165815.jpg
```

4. So the question is why, after accessing url2, I didn't directly retrieve the file content as I expected, but instead popped up the same input account and password box as when accessing url1. Please help me locate the problem
5. my apache version is：Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)

In fact, I have made many attempts, including directly replacing 1% %2 with user1 123456, but all of them are invalid